# How to add avicap32.dll into VS2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm writing a small code in C# using visual studio 2010 express. I'm trying to add **avicap32.dll** from C:\WINDOWS\system32 to the "References" but getting an error saying that **"A reference to 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\avicap32.dll' could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that is a valid assembly or COM component".** How to get rid of this?

thanks in advance,

Sri

Comment: You can't - like the message says, it doesn't contain COM components (or, more to the point, a TLB resource to describe them). You'll need to use pinvoke to access the APIs - hopefully someone can point you at pinvoke wrappers for this? Or something better?

Comment: Have you read [this](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/30375) page?

Comment: hi Rup and Mat thanks for your responses. ;)

Comment: Try this sample project. It has the pInvoke code wrapper for avicap32.dll. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/125478/Versatile-WebCam-C-library

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with this library itself, but I've seen this error many times before when trying to work with 3rd party libraries.  Assuming you've done the diligence in making sure that things are, in fact, accessible and this is not a permissions problem (double check!), this happens when the referenced dll doesn't the .net metadata in it.  Sometimes VS can 'figure it out' even if the metadata isn't explicitly present, but oftentimes it can't. This could be for a number of reasons, but most commonly it's because the dll was written in unmanaged code, like C++.

The solutions to this problem are always in a little bit of flux depending on the specifics of the DLL you're trying to use, and I don't really have too many details on this library you're trying to add.  I picked up a few forum posts that will hopefully set you on the right track, but if not please comment with some extra details so we've got more information to help out.  (Pages: [1](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvcs/thread/c194f361-afcb-47ac-81e9-8be60cbc25a0/) [2](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/clr/thread/b031b6f7-5b56-4ce8-ba10-63d93c9f1fc7/) [3](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/using-c-class-c-t1363942.html))

Comment: Hi YYY, thanks for your response. Page 1 really helped me understanding my problem. ;) i'm looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

[pInvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32.AbortSystemShutdown#) lists many declarations for most of the system dll functions you can try and import. Click on *advapi32* in the left menu and you'll get a list of things they have a declaration for.